# Summarizing functions in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse

How would I add a summary (or description) to my functions in Eclipse, so the text appears in a pop-up box when I select the function?

Comment: [This should help you:](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/documentation/index-137868.html)

Comment: Are function tooltips a feature of the language and not the IDE, then?

Comment: @zEro Please add the link as an answer, it is exactly what I was looking for. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll be able to get the summary and the description as you desire once you've set up documentation for your classes, constructors and methods.

For more details you can look at the [Oracle's documentation on documenting java code](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/documentation/index-137868.html) :)